# How to make regular expression that divides line into words

Tags: java, regex

Tell me please how to make regular expression to separate words.
Lets assume there is string

```
String s = "I have   dog, cat,    gold       fishes.    My cat   eats :      milk,    fish, etc.."
```

I need String array based on that string that looks like

```
 String[] words = s.split(regexp)
```

[I, have, dog, cat, gold, fishes, My, cat, eats, milk, fish, etc]

So regex must ignore whitespaces and punctuation(dots, commas, ?, !, )

Comment: It's a very simple task, if you read a basic tutorial about regex, you will find the answer in two minutes. An advice: using the find method is more easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
String[] words = s.split("[\\s,.:]+");
```

To include all punctuations, use `\p{Punct}`:

```
String[] words = s.split("[\\s\\p{Punct}]+");
```

Comment: You don't need (and shouldn't) escape `.` inside character class. `"[\\s,.:]+"` is enough.

Comment: @Pshemo I missed it. Thank you for the tip.